# Designing High Frequency Signal Amplifier to driver Piezo load

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design

I would appreciate your assistance in designing an amplifier that can drive a 2.4MHz piezo to achieve maximum displacement on its resonance frequency. Please let me know if I am mistaken. I have selected a 2.4MHz piezo as it is commonly used in humidifiers.

I have created a Class AB amplifier that is intended to power the piezo. To construct it, I used two transistors with FJL4315 and FJL4215, each with a continuous current capacity of 17A and a 30MHz bandwidth. These transistors were biased using 2N3904 and 2N3906, which have a continuous current of 200mA and a 300MHz bandwidth.

I have tested my circuit on a 10-ohm load and piezo. The waveforms and schematics are attached.

Channel 1 (Yellow):- Voltage across Load
Channel 2 (Purple):- Voltage across 0.1ohm Series Resistor
Channel 3 (Blue):- Input Signal

Please note that the current measurements have been taken with a 0.1-ohm resistor in series with the load.

Input and Output:-
Input Signal:- 2.88Vrms 2.4MHz
Output Signal (10-ohm Load):- 2.69Vrms 2.4MHz
Current (10ohm Load):- 880mArms

Input Signal:- 2.48Vrms 2.4MHz
Output Signal (Piezo Load):- 1.9Vrms 2.4MHz
Current (10ohm Load):- 1.315Arms

To verify if the piezo is achieving maximum displacement, I poured water over it but it did not atomize. The current drawn is very high, and the voltage across it is very low.
Could you clarify if I need impedance matching for piezo circuits, series resonance circuits, or parallel resonance circuits?

Please suggest improvements to my amplifier design and recommend any ICs that meet my requirements.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

[image: Piezo Load Waveforms]

[image: Resistive Load Waveforms]

Comment: you don't need audio quality to drive power into a piezo, class C and E are the usual choices